# How likely these animals evolved on a sheer cliff?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design

In the world I am designing there is a giant sheer cliff which is so large if you were to jump from the top it would take around 5 minutes to reach the bottom. The cliff is mainly covered in a forest that has trees that jut out horizontally from the cliff face.

### My Question

Could the following creatures actually live on this cliff and if not how could I alter their designs to make them believably survive on the cliff?
[image: The Shifter]

Much like an octopus, the Shifter can change the color and texture of its skin in order blend in with its surroundings, in order to ambush prey that it can tear apart to place in its leech-like mouth.

Comment: There are goats which can walk on almost 90 degree vertical cliffs, there are also birds  who's small chicks can fall from incredible heights and hit the ground without flying, just falling down and sturvive. Check those out to get inspired for your creations

Comment: As written it looks like you're asking us to offer our personal opinions about the plausibility of your critters. Please remember that opinion based questions are off topic on this site.

Comment: I think the bigger issue is how an entire forest grows on a sheer cliff face. Vertically stacked trees will compete for light and water, and have little ability to take hold on sheer rock. There are many examples of animals that live on cliff faces, but I can find no examples of forests that grow on cliff faces.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Also, trees can grow on slopes but grow up anyway. A horizontal tree is basically a very big lever that will pull itself down under its own weight.

Comment: Are we to assume that this creature evolved here on Earth, or on an alien world with tree like vegetation.  If an alien world, what is the gravity?

Comment: consider three things, What does it eat its a big animal thus it needs a lot of calories, how does it climb ( a sketch would help) , and cliff are not a big biome and a big animal needs a large biome to have a significant population consider expanding it to mountains.

Comment: @Nosajimiki The world is an infinite flat plane with the gravity being roughly equal to that of earth throughout the plane, and the vegetation  is similar to that of earths but the wood is considerably sturdier.

Comment: I've slightly edited the question title and added the reality-check tag to ensure a lil' more that what you ask looks more... "Factual" and less opinion-based. Feel free to edit if needed }i{.

Comment: Oops, deleted my 1st comment : you might want to reduce the number of creatures down to 1 per post to get more detailed and focused answers. But now that Willk has answered it might get trickier to do that (edits shouldn't invalidate existing answers).

Comment: I have decided to alter The Shifter's size to roughly half of what it is now to make it more feasible that the trees and rocks it grips onto can support its weight and that it can hunt enough food to support itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Big things in trees?**

I am assuming those things are made of meat like a person.  The top 2 are a lot bigger than people.  I am assuming that these thing are arboreal because trees are what is on the cliff face.  Plus the top one has primate-like hands.  They are huge things to be arboreal, both much bigger than the person placed for scale.  A gorilla is the biggest arboreal creature I can think of.  Even if your beasts are built like birds and very light they are large in size and at risk of hanging up in the branches.

You could make your beasts smaller so they could get around in trees better.

The spider thing is fine but I can't tell how big it is.  I am assuming it is the size of a big spider.  Big spiders exist.

Comment: I think you've noticed, but the question is suffering from 4 close-votes (including mine, though I can understand leaving open), 2 opinions, 2 focus. If it does get closed, would you agree to lend an hand to get it reopened, by editing your answer for instance (their query edits shouldn't invalidate your answer)? It might profit both your works's quality. I'll remove this comment if the situation evolves to a nicer state ^^.

Comment: It seems like when users with 1 rep are told to edit they dont get it and just stop participating.  I have removed 2 of the 3 creatures to improve focus.    Kurtalmakthekoboldkiaser you can post those other creatures as separate questions and just reiterate the vertical tree world piece.

Comment: @Willk Thank you, I will make sure to make sure to make my future questions are more focused and to participate in them more.

Comment: @KurtalmaktheKoboldKiaser Nice! Your question is about to be reopened (1 vote left) and you'll get new answers along with Willk's :).